# Do Italy and Canada share travel and citizenship information of dual citizens?

Tags: international-travel, dual-nationality

I recently received dual citizenship (born Canadian and acquired Italian). I am currently in Canada and last entered the country on my Canadian passport. If I decide to leave Canada on my Italian passport, will the Canadian government be aware of this? Are these two passports linked in any way?  ie. Is the Canadian government even aware that I am now a dual citizen, since I only dealt with the Italian consulate?

Answer (score 13):

No, there's no such sharing.

Canada doesn't do border control on exit; however the check-in staff will transmit data to the CBSA.

At check-in when leaving Canada, you should always present the Canadian passport, as that is what needs to be recorded by the CBSA.

If the check-in staff asks for a return/onward ticket from the Schengen Area, then additionally present your Italian passport.

Comment: CBSA doesn't need to track the movements of Canadian citizens since Canadian citizens cannot violate Canadian immigration law.  It's perfectly acceptable to check in for a flight leaving Canada with an Italian passport. (After ETIAS is implemented, for flights to the Schengen area, it will be necessary.)  Do you have a source supporting your assertion to the contrary?

Answer (score 10):

As a Canadian citizen, the Canadian government does not keep track of, or care, when or how long you are in the country. You may leave at any time without telling anybody. This also means that you can enter Canada at any time and be admitted (assuming you can prove your Canadian citizenship).

For your specific question, you don't have to travel "on" just one passport. See the answers to the question "[I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)", which describes when you need to show each passport at each checkin/border crossing. For a [Canadian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_nationality_law#Multiple_citizenship) and [Italian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_nationality_law#Dual_citizenship) passport combination, it's not very complicated because both countries are fine with their citizens having multiple nationalities.

So, if you are flying to somewhere in Europe for example, check in at the airport, show the ticket agent your Italian passport (so they know you have the right to enter Europe and won't be refused entry), and enjoy your flight.

Note that when leaving Europe, you would want to show your Italian passport to the exit passport check. Canada doesn't have exit passport checks.